# Can I bundle partial HTML and linked CSS into one file using node.js

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, gulp, gruntjs

I work on a project where I only have access to the text editor in CMS, so I create HTML files on local and copy the piece of HTML(content area), CSS and scripts to the CMS editor, is there a way I can use maybe node.js and set up something that can build a file with merged CSS and HTML(content are only) every time I make a change to CSS or HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grunt-processhtml was the answer, I was able to combine CSS, chunk of HTML and JS into one file using this.